# How to get real time image processing using constrained high speed capture session in Android?

Tags: android-ndk, real-time, surfaceview, mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm working on a project that requires real time image processing using
Android smartphone's camera (actually, the Samsung Galaxy S7).

Briefly, the main requirements/conditions are:

- I need to capture and process the images in real-time at high frame rates 
  (ideally 120fps or 240fps, but 60fps would be a good start);
- There is no need to preview the images on display;
- I just need grayscale images (working with nv21 format, this is the first part of the image data).
  So, for efficiency, I would prefer not to convert the images from a native format to jpg and then decode and compute the grayscale data;
- I don't need high resolution images (640x480 would be fine) and the frame processing itself is relatively simple and can be done very fast
  (I just need to scan the grayscale data and extract some basic information);

I have tried a conventional capture using the Camera2 Api with an `ImageReader` surface, but the
best I could get was 37fps (just capturing, not processing), even when turning off the auto control mode, setting bigger ranges for the capture request, 
changing the exposure time, frame duration, etc.

Now, I'm trying to solve the problem using the `CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession` class from the Camera2 Api.
However, the Android reference material says that it should be used for high speed VIDEO RECORDING use case.
Also, according to the documentation, the method `createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession` requires a surface that
must be either a video encoder surface (that could be acquired from a `MediaRecorder`) or a preview surface (obtained from `SurfaceView`, `SurfaceTexture`).
I think that such capture mode uses an special kind of surface/buffer (probably a faster and more efficient one).

Using a preview surface (`SurfaceView`, `SurfaceTexture`), I think I could get stuck in 60fps (the refresh rate of the display). So,
I'm looking for a way to get access to the `BufferQueue` under the `MediaRecorder`'s surface, maybe using NDK/JNI.
The idea is to get access to the raw frame data passed from the camera device to `MediaRecorder`, before the frames be encoded for video purpose.

Please, is this possible? How it could be achieved? Is there a better way?

As an alternative, I have read a litte about `FileDescriptor` with the intention of redirecting the video frames generated by `MediaRecorder`
to a buffer in memory and then try to get access to those frames as they are generated, but it seems to be very inefficient and 
the delay may not be tolerated by the application.

Comment: Not sure if it can achieve your desired frame rate, but you can set a `SurfaceTexture` as a preview surface, render it offscreen to an FBO using opengl and read pixel data using `glReadPixels()` (`glReadPixels()` maybe will be the bottleneck though)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, jfawkes. I'll investigate and test what you've suggested.

Comment: Daniel,

Did you ever get this figured out? I'm interested in doing something similar to what you describe. I want to control the camera, by setting the Sensor_Sensitivity, but also re-process the buffered image before it's sent to the screen.

Comment: Daniel or @Brian did some of you manage to do this?

Comment: I did figure this out. It's complicated, but I used OpenCV in C++ to process images in real time. I could process a 1024 x 1024 at 30 fps.

Comment: @Brian do you have any pointers to how you did it? My requirements are probably less stringent as my image prossesing is extremely simple, but I need high speed. And from my tests now I have only got 60 fps before prosessing. And after it seems to drop to 30 fps by only conversion from YUV to RGB..

Comment: @DanielF, did you managed to do it? I need to implement the same solution but in my case 80-120 fps are enough.